# AWS Redshift Spectrum when accessing files in S3 Glacier deep archive

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We have set up AWS Redshift external table accessing S3 using Spectrum. Due to the huge data amount, we decided to change S3 storage class for files older than 30 days to storage class S3 Glacier Deep Archive using Lifecycle policy.

I couldn't find in the documentation what happens when Redshift Spectrum tries to access data from files which are in Glacier Deep Archive storage class. There are partitions configured so we are aware which files are accessed by queries. Will it result in an error or no data will be returned without an error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Redshift Spectrum don't see archived files at all, so no error, but query result returns data on Standard storage type. This also applies to queries with filter where both S3 file storage types are present.