# AWS Redshift Spectrum does not see restored DeepArchive objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I have a Redshift Spectrum external table backed by Glue with data in S3. To cut cost, S3 data in some partitions has been moved to Deep Archive storage class.

However, one of those partitions is now needed for queries. I've initiated an S3 ObjectRestore and twiddled my thumbs for 12 hours while S3 does its thing. In the console, the S3 data now shows as restored. I've also ensured the Glue partition where the data lives is present and correct.

However, when I query the partition where the data is restored, Redshift returns 0 rows. The partition shows in svv_external_partitions, and I am able to download the object from the S3 path there and read the file. It just seems that Redshift Spectrum is ignoring the restored objects, perhaps because although restored they are still classified as Deep Archive?

Does anyone know if this the expected behavior? I had anticipated that once restored, the data would be queryable in Redshift until the restoration period expired. I can find no mention of this type of case in Redshift or S3 docs. [This posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75833830/aws-redshift-spectrum-when-accessing-files-in-s3-glacier-deep-archive) has a similar question about Spectrum/Deep Archive, but does not ask about data that has been restored.

I also get a similar result when querying the table via Athena.

---

S3 Deep Archive data is restored, Glue partition is present and listed in Redshift's svv_external_partitions.

Querying that partition in Redshift:

**Expected**: Query returns same rows as I see when I download the restored file from S3 and read it manually.

**Actual**: Query returns successfully with 0 rows.

Comment: Did you raise a ticket with AWS Support? They can perhaps explain.

Comment: @nicklon I'm currently facing the same issue. Were you able to get redshift spectrum to be able to read the files? If yes, how did you go about it.

Comment: Last I heard, it's not supported by AWS at this time. They did say objects with Glacier IR storage class are scanned by Spectrum. I haven't verified this myself, but be aware there are retrieval costs associated with Glacier IR if you go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Support has confirmed that reading Deep Archive objects with Spectrum and Athena is not supported at this time.